# How to execute a line of code once?

Tags: php, html

I want to execute a line of code such as:

```
if($sub1="") {
    $a=0;
}
```

only once.  How would I do that?

Comment: Ummmmmm...don't put the line in a loop (and, of course, don't use `goto`)?  Why would a given line of code run more than once during the execution of your php code?

Comment: You need to be more specific. If you go to a PHP page with that code in, it will only be run once, unless you explicitly tell it to run more than once.

Answer (score 5):

change = to == to make it a valid condition

Comment: And for better semantics, he shouldn't even be compared with "", but rather just use `if (empty($sub1))`.

Answer (score 2):

If you run a line of code outside of a loop, it is executed once.

This is the default state. If you tell the computer to make you a sandwich, it will make you just one. If you want two you have to ask for two.

The reason this *particular* code isn't running is likely because you've confused `=` (the assignment operator) and `==` (the equality comparison operator). So you're *setting* `$sub1` to be `""`, instead of *comparing* it with `""`, and the inner block is not executed.